# I cannot see the errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying Laravel and a newbie in it. I installed a fresh copy of Laravel 4 and tried some sample codes. But couldn't see the errors as I see I the sample videos. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `app->Config->app.php`
Make the `'debug'=>true;`
Then you are good to go! 
But make sure it's false in the production environment.